# cant run java control panel in oracle jdk1.8.0_51

Tags: software-installation, java, jdk, oracle

I have download jdk1.8.0_51 as oracle documentation and place it where in .java directory . now i want to open java conrol panel but unable to do . what should I do to open it. So I can enable java logs.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Oracle Java from PPA

```
sudo apt-get install ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

In this case installation scripts will do everything for you and create shortcuts to control panel. They will appear in Dash.

Comment: No i want to do manualy . Tell me how i can do

Comment: You can start it manually, but it depends on where did you install it.